# Flexbox and box-sizing makes flex items too small

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I've used `display: flex` to create a simple Header, Content, Footer box where Header and Footer are fluid height, and Content takes up the remaining height.

This works fine in Firefox but in Chrome both Header and Footer are too small to fit their content.

I managed to track it down to the use of `box-sizing: border-box`. Removing it solves the issue. But I'd like to know if this is a known bug, or perhaps even a feature?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3Lb72vz/1/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; // Comment this out to see how header and footer grow to fit their content
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

.popup {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  // Center the box
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  &__box {
    background: #fff;
    
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 20rem;
    max-height: 80%;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  &__header,
  &__content, 
  &__footer {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  
  &__header {
    background: red;
    
    h2 {
      margin: 0;
      background: green;
    }
  }
  
  &__footer {
    background: green;
    
    p {
      background: red;
    }
  }
  
  &__content {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="popup" id="my-popup">
  <div class="popup__box">
    <header class="popup__header">
      <h2>Test</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="popup__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="popup__footer">
      <p>Footer footer footer footer.</p>
      <p>Footer footer footer footer.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ugrage u chrome. in last version its all right. or use autoprefixer and -webkit-flex

Comment: It's a great question. Strange behavior indeed. If you find a solution please post an answer.